# Using ALSA instead Pulseaudio and "logout" issue (14.04.1)

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a usb dac and I would like to use ALSA instead of Pulseaudio.

First, I [stopped the pulseaudio](http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/) permanently:

```
echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
pulseaudio -k
```

Alsamixer gets *cannot open mixer: No such file or directory* error. Creating basic *.asoundrc* file with my default "hardware output" device solved this issue.
Unmuting *IEC958 (SPDIF)*, sound is working properly now.

But there is big issue for me. 
Output is muted after logout (rebooting does not cause this problem). Login back **doesn't restoring settings** from alsamixer *asound.state* file - **IEC958 (SPDIF) is muted**...

Only running `sudo alsactl restore` restore this settings properly. Adding user to audio group did not help.

Should I prepare `alsactl restore` script for logging or something other I missing?

Comment: In theory, `alsactl restore` should be run automatically, but it appears you did not deactive PulseAudio completely.

Comment: Something in it. Previously, I completely removed pulseaudio and did not have this problem. Now I do not want to do that, because there are too many dependencies. But I care very to use alsa instead of pulse...

Comment: If Ubuntu assumes that PA is always used, it will never bother to call `alsactl restore` in the first place.

Comment: It's a shame that Canonical does not give tips on how to painlessly use ALSA instead of PA by default. I think that by this a lot of people simply purge the pulseaudio for "bitperfect" output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sound is muted at alsa level (as shown using alsamixer), you can unmute editing or creating `.profile` file in your home, and adding these commands in it:
 they will be executed when session start:

`#!/bin/bash 
amixer set Digital unmute 
amixer set Master unmute 
amixer set Headphone unmute`

Look the faders name in alsamixer and replace  if necessary (may be  "Digital"  becomes "IEC958 (SPDIF)" )

Comment: Yes, `sudo alsactl store 1` or default `sudo alsactl store` gives me same and correct result. I think that editing the startup file is reasonable way. I tried edit `rc.local` without success. I'm not sure if this file is not accessible only for system start - reboot does not mute the output, logout only. And relogin didn't restore alsamixer settings (unmuting). Edit `etc\profile` file is a good way perhaps?

Comment: Ok , my previous answer was out of subject, i edited it.

Comment: `amixer` fit my needs, great suggestion. BTW. I discovered that XBMC (what I use with ALSA) gives ALSA sink option for Ubuntu and other "PulseAudio" distributions now.