# why only a reboot solves pulseaudio "muted"?

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio

I have read thru many places saying what we can do to make pulseaudio work again, but nothing makes it work, they also mainly seem targeted to a "not working at all" situation, but here it works again after reboot.

So, here, only a reboot makes it work, and many times I cant just do that.

So, if I make pulseaudio stop:
https://askubuntu.com/a/10307/46437
`service pulseaudio stop` or `pulseaudio -k`

I can at least use `aplay` or `mplayer` they seem to try pulse and fallback to alsa, what is ok.

But for ex. videos on chromium+youtube will not start working when I stop pulseaudio.

I learned that if I start it as `pulseaudio -vvvvv` it will show some log that appears to be useful, but what should I look at there to understand why I have no sound thru it, even if using the system audio controls (when it is enabled) I see clearly it is not muted and is at 100% volume?

If I let it enabled, and play something thru `aplay`, pulseaudio's log will show it is playing something but there is no sound at all...

I checked at `alsamixer` and nothing is muted either: https://askubuntu.com/a/540219/46437

Comment: if we take down pulseaudio, everything seems to default to alsa as soon we restart the application!

Comment: tried restarting pulseaudio instead of killing ?

Comment: @Serg yes many times with `service pulseaudio restart`, also `pulseaudio -k` that makes the daemon auto restart if we keep the autospawn config file option enabled

Comment: I found another interesting thing, if "alarm clock" applet is running an alarm playing a long music during startup, it will interfere with pulseaudio proper initialization (it seems to block pulseaudio and keep playing only in alsa?)! so now I delay it's startup with a script `secDelayedExec.sh -d -w -s 120 alarm-clock-applet --hidden`